# Couldn't create IBOutlet, IBAction and subclasses in Xcode 8.3.3

Tags: ios, xcode

In Xcode I can't connect the IBOutlet and IBAction through the storyboard. It doesn't show the subclasses I created of new classes. And suggest completion while typing is not also working. I tried reinstalling Xcode but it didn't work. Kindly post your suggestions.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for your response and corrections. * See this is not a Xcode issue. It’s occurred in my machine only. Thats why I mentioned “In My Xcode tool”. * It doesn't show the subclasses I created of new classes. - I have denoted in this issue occurs during that time only. * I tried reinstalling Xcode but it did't work - here there isn’t mean for did’t. Its Didn’t right. (Firstly, could you please check your grammar first after that you may correct others.)

Answer (score 0):

1).Setup your class in storyboard.
[image]

2). Follow this screen short.

[image]

Comment: I was tried this method.In this method also not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add them manually(using @IBOutlet) and connect them by drap and drop method. It works everytime with me.

Comment: i doing this method it takes more time

Comment: If you get used to it... It actually saves time... Because you can manually define outlets, write the whole code and then connect them

Comment: Instead of drag and drop... You can also connect them from storyboard... Go to the last tab of view controller which shows the outlets, delgates etc... And connect it to your view